# Connecting my WSGI application to my PostgreSQL database using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, apache, psycopg2, wsgi

I'm running an Apache web server hosting a Python3 application using WSGI.  My WSGI application needs to connect to a PostgreSQL using psycopg2 but when I pass the username and password in the connection string I get the error message FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username".  I'm certain that the username and password is correct.  The database was created under a specific user account and I'm assuming the issue is because Apache is running as root.  But I thought that supplying the credentials in my WSGI app would address that.  Do I need to create a new PostgreSQL database under the root user account to use with Apache/WSGI?  Here's some simple code that I used to test my connection:

```
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask, render_template
cn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydatabase', user='username', host='localhost', password='password')
print ("Connected")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `psql` to connect to the database with the same credentials? The database is separate from Apache, it should be reachable using the appropriate credentials without running as root.

Comment: Was able to resolve this by modifying the hb_pg.conf file.  I enabled trust authentication for all local connections.  I understand the obvious security issues here but I'll use this for now.  Later I will look to configure peer authentication and user name map.